# ng_validators and ng_value_accessor together

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Why my validators aren't visiblein my outer-form (app.ts)

here's my code https://plnkr.co/edit/V4qLTMAZExaRJXFljtQf?p=preview

```
providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressControlComponent), multi: true },
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressControlComponent), multi: true }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

no it's not possible  direct but you want this so use sub model